# Как получить текущий URL перед событием popstate

Tags: javascript, html5-history-api

Необходимо получить URL который был до того, как пользователь нажал на кнопку back в браузере.
Я слушаю событие "popstate" но выходит что я работаю уже с "новой страницей" и url уже новый.

```
window.addEventListener ("popstate", function (e) {
    console.log(location.pathname.split("/").pop());
    console.log('Тут писать предыдущий url');
}
```

В итоге: консоль даёт мне новую концовку url.

Сделать так не вариант:

```
let endpath = location.pathname.split("/").pop();
```

Потому, что `history.pushState` вызывается на странице много раз. 
Думаю над вариантом собрать все посещённые "страницы" в массив и просто шагать по нему в обратном порядке. Но вдруг есть более лаконичное решение?

Answer (score 1):

Так можно же запоминать текущий url и с которого пришли на стр, и сравнивать их с учётом get или без, как больше подходит... Или нет?

Answer (score 0):

Решение оказалось простое, решил передавать старую страницу при событии`history.pushState`

```
history.pushState({'page':currentLoc,'oldPage':endpath}, "Title", currentLoc);
```

Затем можно позвать с помощью

```
console.log(history.state.oldPage);
```

Comment: Эмм, так я же и предложил тож самое :))

Comment: Держи лайк)))))

Comment: Ну спасибо))) у меня такого завались ток спрашивать успевай ))